# Independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ are such that $E(X^2)=4$, $E(Y^2)=20$, $\text{Var}(X)=10$, $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=11$. Find $E(3X-2Y)$.

Tags: random-variables

I know how to find the expected value $E(X)$ of a random variables but I don't know how the $E(X^2)$ is related to $E(X^2)$ when the $X$ variables are not given. Let's say if $X=x$ where $x=1,2,3,4$. Then I could be able to deduce both $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$.

Comment: E(X^2) = E(X^2).  (Written in your post.   Are you asking how  $E(X^2)$ and $E(Y^2)$ are related?

Comment: Use the fact that $Var(X) = E[X]^2 - E[X^2]$ and similar for $Y$ to find $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ and then use the fact that $E[3X-2Y] = 3E[X]-2E[Y]$

Answer (score 0):

$10=\operatorname{Var}(X)=EX^{2}-(EX)^{2}=4-(EX)^{2}\leq 4$. So there are no such random variables!